# Is it possible to merge these tables into one array value

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to combine some data from three different tables into a usuable array but I'm stuck on how to approach this.

First let me explain the structure:

My 'main' table `snm_content` :

I only want to use `id` here

[image]

Second table 'snm_fieldsandfilters_connections' :

`element_id` is important here, it has the same value as `id` in the next table

[image]

Third table 'snm_fieldsandfilters_elements':

Here `item_id` is important and `item_id` is the same value as `id` in 'snm_content'

[image]

So for example I add another article (the items in snm_content) which has `id` 4, then another row will be added in 'snm_fieldsandfilters_connections' with `element_id` 22 and there will also be another row added to 'snm_fieldsandfilters_elements' with `id` 22 and `item_id` 4.

How can I get `element_id` from'snm_fieldsandfilters_connections' to match the `id` in 'snm_fieldsandfilters_elements'? And then compare `id` from 'snm_content' with `item_id` from 'snm_fieldsandfilters_elements'.

I hope I explained it well enough.

What is the best way to achieve this? (I mean SQL wise)

Thanks to the answer I figured out how to do it.

SOLUTION:

```
select ct.*, fe.*, cn.*
from snm_content ct
inner join snm_fieldsandfilters_elements fe on fe.item_id = ct.id
inner join snm_fieldsandfilters_connections cn on cn.element_id = fe.id
WHERE ct.catid IN ('10')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking about combining data from different tables. The way to do this is using SQL JOINs. I suggest you read up on them if you're not aware of how to use them. In the meantime, as an example, this should solve your specific problem, if I've understood the requirements correctly:

```
select ct.id 
from snm_content ct
inner join snm_fieldsandfilters_elements fe on fe.item_id = ct.id
inner join snm_fieldsandfilters_connections cn on cn.id = fe.element_id
```

Comment: I am ware how to use them, but having a hard time thinking out this query in a logical way. The code you posted doesn't work when I execute it. I'm using InnoDB in phpmyadmin if that helps.

Comment: This is the error I get: '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from snm_content ct inner join snm_fieldsandfilters_elements fe on fe.item_id = ' at line 2
'

Comment: @twan sorry, didn't mean to offend. your current level of knowledge wasn't clear from the question. I have edited the answer - there was a stray comma at the end of line 1

Comment: No worries :p you didn't offend me. The edited answer shows: #1054 - Unknown column 'c.id' in 'field list' Don't I need to assign c.id first? Like: id as c.id

Comment: @twan sorry edited again. It should be ct.id (as in, using the alias ct of table snm_content). Of course, that's only an example, you can change it to output whatever fields you actually require.

Comment: Thanks that SQL works, but only returns the id of snm_content. I need everything from snm_content so that would be ct.* and then the field_value_id that matches the snm_content_id but they aren't connected straight away, they are connected through element_id and id being the same in snm_fieldsandfilters_connections and snm_fieldsandfilters_elements with item_id in snm_fieldsandfilters_elements being the same as id in snm_content

Comment: @twan you should be able to select any of the fields you want from any of the tables all at the same time. so, you could do `select ct.*, cn.field_value_id` or any other combination you need. Just change the example query I've given to suit yourself. If you're not sure what to select, maybe start with `select *` and look at the output, and then decide what you need and alter it as you go along. My point was to demonstrate how to join the tables together logically, using the relationships you described in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out using your code. Should I post the solution as a seperate answer? I'll accept yours first.

Comment: you can if you like (probably an edit to your original question is a good place to do it), but I suspect that people coming here in future will be more interested in the general principle (i.e. using joins and selecting the fields). They probably won't want to select the exact same fields as you.